# Why does the first nth-child select all of them?

Tags: html, css

Consider:

```css
nav ul li .linav a:nth-child(1):before,
nav ul li .linav a:nth-child(1):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, goldenrod, yellow);
  background-color: crimson;
}

nav ul li .linav a:nth-child(2):before,
nav ul li .linav a:nth-child(2):after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkred, #F80F01);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Animated Navigation Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <h1 class="brand"><a class='nav' href="index1.html"><span class="textgradient">Golden</span><span class="textgradient2">Adr</span><span class="textgradient3">ien</span></a></h1>
        <ul class="ulnav">
          <li class="linav"><a class='nav' href="#">Social Links</a></li>
          <li class="linav"><a class='nav2' href="#">Programs</a></li>
          <li class="linav"><a class='nav3' href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <p>
      Hey! Welcome to my website.<br> On here I have my social links and will be posting some of my html/css/javascript programs as well. Also this is my first website so please don't be too harsh about it. Thanks!
    </p>
  </header>
</body>
```

I can't get my code to work the way I want it to. I want each of the nth-childs to have their own color. My goal is for the to buttons to have different colored lines.

Comment: share your html code ... but I guess you have only one `a` inside your `li` and you have to target the `li` instead

Comment: It'd be easier to help you out if you could create a snippet so we can see the actual error happening

Comment: it is has a snippet now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your HTML, all `a` tags is always the first child of `li`. Try to put the `:nth-child(1)` in `li` instead.

Also, I want point out the `li .linav` in your CSS selector. It means you are selecting the `.linav` inside `li`. It should be no space (`li.linav`) so the CSS will look for `li` that has a `.linav` class.

```css
nav ul li.linav:nth-child(1) a:before
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had been struggling with that a ton.

Comment: Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a:before,
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, goldenrod, yellow);
  background-color: crimson;
 }
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a:before,
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, darkred, #F80F01);
}
```

Comment: Could you state what you changed pleass?